# Blank screen when booting from USB drive

Tags: 12.04, boot, 64-bit, live-usb

Here is what I have done:

1. I downloaded the iso "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64"
2. I used Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.0.0 to make a bootable USB drive.
3. I restarted PC and changed the boot option to USB HDD.
4. I got a menu to:

   - Boot from USB
   - Install to hard drive
   - Help
   - etc
5. When I click *Boot from USB* or *Install to hard drive*, loads of text flies past and then I get a blank screen and I can't see anything.

What can I do so I can see the installation screen? I'm using a dual monitor setup from my GFX card and my main display is on my HDMI port to my TV.

Comment: Anybody want to suggest `nomodeset`?

Comment: Do you see anything at all when booting from USB? If this is your first time installing Ubuntu 12.04, then right when you boot from usb, try and hit the 'F6' key while at the GRUB menu, then adding "b43.blacklist=yes" (without quotations) to the end of the Ubuntu line and try booting up normally. If 'F6' doesn't work, try pressing 'e' instead and doing the exact same thing. The usual problem is booting screen lockup, because of a firmware error. When you press 'Esc' during bootup it will show what is loading, and then, if any errors occur, it will say what the problem is and usually it is the

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use 1 monitor untill you have completely installed Ubuntu, secondly I would need more details about your computer but you should be disabling UEFI boot from the USB and try to run it legacy mode. Please give as much information as possible, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of a corrupted `.iso` image, or a bad write.

- To check if the `.iso` image you downloaded is corrupted, [MD5 test it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).
- To check if the write to the USB flash drive is corrupted (or otherwise not working), [verify the installation media](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html). (This says "Check disc for defects" but it applies equally to a USB flash drive.)

This could, alternatively, be the result of video compatibility problems.

- If that is happening, then as [ObsessiveFOSS](https://askubuntu.com/users/54298/obsessivefoss) commented, [setting the `nomodeset` boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) may help.

If none of these suggestions help, then you should **edit your question** to described what happened when you tried them, and also to **add the exact make and model of your computer** to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the bootable USB with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

I also had problems with Universal-USB-Installer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue for a long time, now i believe i have the answer.

Just go to your BIOS, and make sure that SATA mode is on IDE. Otherwise you will only be able to install the 32 bits version of the OS.

Comment: But how are they  related?